# Shopify Python API GET Metafields for a Product

Tags: python, shopify

Is there a way to GET the metafields for a particular product if I have the product ID? Couldn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

The call you want is `shopify.Metafield.find()`

```
>>> shopify.Metafield.find()
[metafield(1), metafield(2), metafield(3)]
```

You can also pass in filters

```
>>> shopify.Metafield.find(namespace='myapp')
[metafield(1), metafield(2)]
```

The Python API has almost zero documentation which makes figuring these things out an exercise in frustration.

Answer (score 1):

A easy way to do it in python would be:

```
product = shopify.Product({"id" : product_id})
metafields = product.metafields()
```

Note that the above would be one API call, finding product and then metafields would be two API calls:

```
product = shopify.Product.find(product_id)
metafields = product.metafields()
```

a bit hacky but works well with the python package

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Metafields API](https://docs.shopify.com/api/metafield). In particular, you can use the endpoint

`GET /admin/products/#{id}/metafields.json`

to get metafields that belong to a particular product.

Answer (score 0):

product = shopify.Product.find(pr_id)

metafields = product.metafields()

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the way @lihuangxiao suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48191928/1237117). But modify it slightly to avoid two API calls:

```
product = shopify.Product({id: product_id})
metafields = product.metafields()
```